# Notation for matrix with $0$'s and $1$'s

Tags: abstract-algebra

I read the [article about permutation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix). It makes me wonder if there is some canonical notation for a matrix with everywhere $0$ except at position $(m, \, n)$. I know I can represent it by vector product $e_i \, e_j^\intercal$ or set $\{\delta_{im} \, \delta_{jn}\}_{\, i, j \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Some would use something like $E_{m,n}$ (for the one such that $(E_{m,n})_{m,n}=1$ ).

Comment: Grazie, Giulio.

Comment: Also $\mathbf{e}_{mn}$. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_basis

Comment: Oh, sure! It is canonical basis for matrix space! I am getting old...